# Why is my repeating group not being captured?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

Using: scala.util.parsing.combinator

```scala
  def varToken: Parser[ZVAR] = """[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*""".r ^^ { str => println("varToken: "+str);ZVAR(str) }
  def number: Parser[ZNUMBER] = """-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d*)?""".r ^^ { str => ZNUMBER(str) }
  def dot: Parser[ZDOT] = """\.""".r ^^ { _ => ZDOT() }

  def ref: Parser[_] = varToken ~ refArgDot.* ^^ {r => println("ref: "+r)} // ascii token + optional repeating "dot" notations
  def refArgDot = dot ~ varToken ^^ { a => println("Dot: "+a)}
  val define = ref ~ number.* // top-level match
```

Input string:

```
foo.bar.baz 1 2 3
```

Output:

```
varToken: foo
varToken: bar
Dot: (ZDOT()~ZVAR(bar))
varToken: baz
Dot: (ZDOT()~ZVAR(baz))
ref: (ZVAR(foo)~List((), ()))
```

Matching (top-level) against define.
You can see the varTokens match as expected, as do the dots (refArgDot).
But look at the ref:  I expect it to capture [foo,dot,bar,dot,baz] but it only captures foo and nothing else.

It's basically failing to capture the ref properly.

I would have expected something along the lines of:

```
ref: (ZVAR(foo)~List(List(ZDOT()~ZVAR(bar)), List(ZDOT()~ZVAR(baz))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The println blocks are swallowing the return value.  Should be:

```scala
def ref: Parser[_] = varToken ~ refArgDot.* ^^ {r => println("ref: "+r); r}
```